# Call function on jquery ui dialog open (any and all dialogs)

Tags: jquery, dialog

I'm trying to run a function on the open and close of *all* dialogs without having to add the 'open' and 'close' functions to each and every dialog instance. So something like this happens when any dialog is opened or closed:

```
$("#any_and_all_dialogs").dialog({
    open: function () {
        // do stuff
    },
    close: function () {
        // do other stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there anything in particular that doesn't work? Have you tried something and experienced any problems? The draft code that you posted looks like it could roughly work.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something when the dialog is opened.

```
(function() {
   $('#any_and_all_dialogs').dialog({
      open: function() {
          // do stuff on load
       };
   });
}());
```

Comment: Right, but how do I target *all* dialogs (vs. my single example "any_and_all_dialogs") ?

Comment: Iterate through dialogs based on their Id. Let me know if you still could not get it

Comment: $.each($("#any_and_all_dialogs"), function (i, d) { 
   d.dialog({
      open: function() {
          // do stuff on load
       };
   });
});

Comment: #any_and_all_dialogs is fake... it doesn't exist... each dialog has a unique ID, but no common class. Maybe $.each($('.ui-dialog')...?

Comment: Id or class does not matter, preferred is to use class but its ok to use id.

What you can do is, get all unique ids in array then iterate on that array to invoke your dialog. I posted enhanced solution above this post. what you need to dos is replace '#any_and_all_dialogs' with yourArray[i] to check each dialog

Comment: I would guess the asker wants a way to run the function when ANY dialog is opened, even if the class or id is not known. I image it's not possible unless you can effectively extend the dialog event itself.